# How to use Matcher to properly replace all occurences of a pattern inside a string

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I am using a `Matcher` to find specific patterns in a `String` that contains a text.
The regular expression checks for various patterns e.g. for simplicity:
`\\bword1\\b|(\\b(?:word2(?:(\\s+)word3)?)?)`  etc

Anyway I can find the patterns in the string.
So far ok.

What I want though, is to be able to use the `Matcher.replaceAll` in order to replace each pattern found, **with the same pattern** but with some addition.

E.g.

If the matcher finds `word1` somewhere, I want to replace it with `{v}word1{v}`.

How is this best done?I tried to add the groups that matcher finds in a list and then loop over the input string to replace all but obviously this did not work.

**UPDATE:**
I can match the terms I need and @Luis regex does the replace, but I need to replace **all** in my String.
By looping and doing the regex `"pattern", "{v}$0{v}")` inside the string I break previous occurences I made. I need to somehow include a negative lookbehind in the replaceAll so as to **understand when a term has already been replaced**

**UPDATE:**
Using @Luis regex and negative lookbehind it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED:

`"pattern".replaceAll("pattern", "{v}$0{v}"))`

I've tested this and it returns "{v}pattern{v}" as desired.

Comment: I will give you a +1 but this does not solve my problem.When I loop to do replaceAll for each term found, I break previous modifications, since I can have a match `word1 word2` and later in the string `word2` the second replaceAll breaks the `word1 word2` found earlier

Comment: I think I need somehow the negative look behind in your statement

Comment: That wasn't clear from your original question.  I suspect your best bet might be not to do a replaceAll for each term -- in which case it's almost impossible to avoid the problem you describe -- but to modify your original pattern to match each of the individual patterns.

Comment: Not sure what you mean.My original pattern does match the individual terms.My problem is in their replacement.I think I don't follow you.

Comment: You should do only a single replaceAll call, and you should try to replace all of the individual terms at once: so e.g. "(?:word1 word2)|(?:word2)" instead of "word1 word2" and then "word2".  If that doesn't work -- perhaps you need to do different things each time -- then it becomes a harder problem.

Comment: I see what you are saying.But I don't know how to replace the terms in a single `replaceAll`.That is why I tried via a loop